# Validate DMN rule not overlap while adding new rule to DMN table

Tags: java, angularjs, camunda

I am using camunda DMN in my application(in angular, java, spring).

I want to validate if rule is not overlapping while adding new rule to DMN table.

for example following is my DMN table,

---

## | x   |  y     |   o/p  |

| <9  |  >50   |  "ABC" |

| <20 |  >100  |  "XYZ" |

Consider user is so dumb :D , and can create rules like above.

Now if i/p's for above DMN are x = 10 and y = 99 then it satisfy both rules.

If I use UNIQUE hit policy, it wont show me error at the time of add new rule rather it will show me while evaluation of DMN table. And I dont want that :(

**How to avoid overlapping of rules while creating of rule it self using either camunda dmn js api or camunda dmn java api ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible as it would require knowledge about all the possible input combinations. Also to infer the overlapping value range of all rules can be quite hard.

Comment: Thank you for answer :). Just one question, is there java function for example considering dmn table in question which return me all rules where x = 10 (say x input will not have any expression. it will only have number)

Comment: No maybe you could use the [DMN model API](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model) to implement such a function. It is a wrapped around the DMN XML structure and allows you to access the different elements, eg see the [tests](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model/blob/master/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/model/dmn/ExampleTest.java#L128-L140).

Comment: Danke :) Link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian pointed out there is no built-in functionality to achieve this. However, we discussed in a project that you could create a parameterized JUnit test case and run it with all permutations of input possibilities yourself. You will get an exception if you call the decision table with an input which does not have a unique result.

Cheers
Bernd

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07466v1.pdf, this could help. There is a link in the document to a github project with dmn-js where a rules validtion is added, also to an online version where you can see how it works.